# Create socket connection with Bluetooth device after ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I can get a working connection from a Bluetooth device if my application is waiting on an 'accept' call prior to the ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED broadcast being received.  If I issue the 'accept' call in response to the broadcast being received I can't make the socket connection.

Is there a way to make this happen so I can setup the socket connection in response to the Bluetooth event?

Comment: You can start a server after a broadcast:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15662892/2046601

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a way to accept in response to an  ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED, this is designed to work similar to regular TCP sockets, the listening only happens (which in bluetooth terms means registering the service UUID in the SDP record and waiting for incoming connections) when the accept() call is made.

You can try accept(timeout) if you are concerned about blocking on the accept call and cant afford to have a dedicated thread to block on the accept()

Comment: If I build the app so that it waits on an accept for a SPP connection anytime this well known profile is used by a client device my application will take the accept and start processing.   But what happens if the SPP profile connect from the client device is for a different application?  I was hoping that I could look at the low level ACL connect broadcast to determine if the device that just went on the air is a device that my app can talk to, if not I would ignore the connect broadcast.

Comment: The behavior I was hoping for is that if an app tried an 'accept' the bluetooth stack would first look and see if a device has a low level connect active and might be trying the socket connect.  If the stack didn't find one of these 'unanswered' connects it would block normally.

Comment: Your application will register and identify itself via the UUID (which will be unique for different application) when a remote device discovers , it finds your application/service via this UUID, then it connects to this UUID, so when you wait on accept() for a connection you are waiting to connections to this UUID. So even if multiple applications are using SPP, the accept() will be directed based on UUID. Further you can always disconnect from devices that you don't want to connect with. (if you have the means of knowing the devices you don't want to connect with)

Comment: If it were an application I was controlling that would work,  unfortunately it is a device that I can't control, and it using the well known SPP UID.    THe device bulders would have been much better off using thier own unique UID, but that ship sailed about 100,000 devices ago.